# Navigation Menu Not Working For Other Activities - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, menu, navigation

I am programming a navigation menu for my app. The app starts with a login screen then moves into the main activity. From there, a navigation bar can be swiped open on the left and you are taken to any of the pages. The menu will let me go from main activity to one page, but then on that page I can go back to main activity by clicking home, but cannot go to any other activities. This is my first time programming in java and android studio so I am trying to learn all I can. I tried using this same section in main activity and just changing the intent, so for the personal page using **new intent(personal.this, vehicle.class)** or whatever and it won't work but if I do **new intent(personal.this, mainactivity.class)** that does work.

Nav drawer:

````
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="start">
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_drawer"
    layout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>```
````

MainActivity.java

````
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_account)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, account.class));
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                }

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                }

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_personal)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, personal.class));
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                }```

[![Nav menu][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzomy.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Why you added `Intent intent = getIntent()` after startActivity. `getIntent()` works for sending `Strings, int, bool` from one Activity to Second Activity.

```
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Just remove this line if you just want to go from the first to the second activity. See your new code below.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_account)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, account.class));
                }

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_logout)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
                }

                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_personal)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, personal.class));
                }
```

If you getting the same issue. Let me know by commenting

Comment: So I removed all of the getIIntents() and that still did not fix the issue. The issue is the same. So I have a login.class, then that goes to MainActivity.class and from there I can go to several pages: my account, personal, logout, etc. They all work from the main activity menu, but when I go to any of the pages otherwise such as personal and do the same thing, it will only let me go back to main activity. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Bella Ok, let me explain, you created an app with Drawer Navigation and added some menus in drawer ryt. When you click on any menu of drawer you redirect to that activity like account, personal, and after coming home (Main activity). You cannot go to any other menu??? Am I right?? if not please explain me clearly by adding an image to your question. I'll definatly solve your problem if I understand it clearly.

Comment: Yes I created the drawer navigation and added menus. Here are my pages: Home, my account, logout, personal, vehicle, medical. When I am in MainActivity.java I can go to any page. I copied and pasted that code above to another page like personal and then changed it from MainActivity.this to whatever page im on so personal would be: personal.this and it works when I click Main Activity -> personal but then personal cannot go to my account, logout, medical, or vehicle, it can only go back to Main Activity